# Paw - dynamic values are repeated in request body

Tags: paw-app

I have a request with a body that includes a list of users like so:

```
{
  "scheduled_start": "2015-12-17 17:00:00",
  "session_type": "0",
  "members": [
    {
      "host": true,
      ...
      "user": {
        "uuid": {uuid},
        ...
      }
    },
    {
      "host": false,
      ...
      "user": {
        "uuid": {uuid},
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the uuid field for the user is using the dynamic [uuid extension](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/RandomUuidValue). The problem is, the uuid is not unique for each user. It seems like PAW is caching the result and using the same value for each user in the request body. The same behavior is happening for the random email and name extensions.

How can I get distinct values for these fields in the request body?

Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou for finding this bug I will follow up on it for know as a work around you can wrap you second value inside a custom dynamic value. 

However you are correct it seams to be catching the value for each type of dynamic value. If you need more that 2 you will need to get creative, possibly creating environment vars etc.